# Issue with Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2.1

Tags: shared-library, 19.04, libpng

I'm new to troubleshooting in Linux in general and this goes as my first post here. I'm having trouble installing Cisco Packet Tracer on Ubuntu 19.04 mainly because of a dependency for 'libpng12-0' packet. Now as far as I can understand is that I have 'libpng16' by default on my system and going back a version from 16 > 12 raises some concerns.

My question is, could this dependency be within the PT and can I modify this dependency to match the 16 version already on my system.

Comment: The dependency isn't available since Ubuntu 16.10, I think. But I installed the one available for 16.04 to solve a similar problem with a another software. I didn't notice any problems because of that but can't guarantee there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency is not within the packet tracer. I guess you need to download "libpng12-0" 
I had to download it to get it installed. I am new too so don't have much idea. I downloaded packet tracer 7.2.1 from [Here](https://infotechtx.com/cisco-packet-tracer-download/)